# MySQL AS in JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table (edu_posts) which contains posts. The field "post_receiver" usually contains a user_id, but sometimes it may contain an event ID (syntax:  event-ID) and I have created a statement like this:

```
  SELECT 
    p.*, 
    u.firstname AS post_author_firstname, 
    u.lastname AS post_author_lastname, 
    u3.firstname AS receiver_firstname, 
    u3.lastname AS receiver_lastname, 
    pl.like_author AS user_likes,
    CASE
    WHEN p.post_receiver REGEXP '^[a-z]'
    THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_receiver, '-', 2), 
      '-', 
      - 1
    )
    END
    AS event_id,
    e.event_name AS event_name
  FROM 
    edu_posts p 
    LEFT JOIN edu_users u ON u.user_id = p.post_author 
    LEFT JOIN edu_users u3 ON u3.user_id = p.post_receiver 
    LEFT JOIN edu_likes pl ON pl.like_entity = p.post_id
    LEFT JOIN edu_events e ON e.event_id = event_id

    AND pl.like_author = 1 
  GROUP BY 
    p.post_id, 
    pl.like_id 
  ORDER BY 
    p.post_date DESC
```

Have a look at CASE and below in the SELECT statement, and the last LEFT JOIN.

I figured I cannot retrieve data from "event_id" i created in the SELECT statement. So what could I do to LEFT JOIN based on EVENT_ID's value?

Maybe this whole progress is too complicated, and instead it would be better and more effective to make a new MySQL call in the PHP code, if post_receiver is equal to: event-someID?

What are your thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to post some sample data and the corresponding expected result, since your task is not clear.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ... ON CASE
    WHEN p.post_receiver REGEXP '^[a-z]'
    THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_receiver, '-', 2), 
      '-', 
      - 1
    )
    END = 123`. `ON` clause accepts any expression, not just in `col = col2` form

Comment: My thoughts are that you shouldn't store 2 different kinds of data in one field.  That's why this is complicated.  You should have 2 fields, one for UserID, one for EventID.  You can enforce that exactl 1 field is non null at a time.

Comment: Thank you Zerkms. I used this code: `ON e.event_id = CASE WHEN p.post_receiver REGEXP '^[a-z]' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_receiver, '-', 2), '-', - 1 ) ELSE 'x' END` Strange problem now though; only ONE single event has "event_name" filled out - rest is NULL. I have tried chaning the row 'event-8' to fx 'event-6' and it will change.

Comment: @BillGregg , What would be smartest? Having an extra field with the event_id in or to do an additional query inside the loop to fetch event name? I'm thinking effectiveness and optimization.

Comment: An extra field makes more sense from a data modeling perspective.  If you keep your data model simple and straight forward, it makes working with your model simple and straight forward.  When you are joining on a case statement, you are causing headaches for you and your DB engine.